# Default payment methods are not showing

Tags: magento-1.9, module, ce-1.9.1.0, payment

I'm using Magento 1.9.1.

I have really strange problem which i noticed not far ago.
When i installed this module: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bankpayment.html and i've set it active from the admin panel i've noticed that the payment method is not showing up.

Then i've set active and few other default payment methods that come with the magento installation and none of them showed as active.

It's important to say that i've deactivated the cache and cleared it.
Compilation mode is disabled.

Also i've tried to create some custom payment module which files i've deleted later on before i installed the BankPayment module.(I know that there is an Bank Transfer payment module already installed with magento, but i want to install this one)

Can you give me any advices, what should i check or where can be the problem and eventually how to fix it?

Comment: Did you check your logs to make sure you are not getting any errors? Can you activate SAVE CC? Do you have any shopping cart rules?

Comment: I can activate it but it is not showing it. How can i chech for errors ?

Comment: You will have to look at your error logs. Make sure logging is on in Magento

Comment: @TonyStark were you able to solve this? If so, how?